# extract words from file, then count frequency

Tags: java, string, file, count, cpu-word

I'm currently dealing with 20 txt files, the task is to count words frequency for each word, and then output the result into a single txt file...

For example: word --"news"  appears 47 times in 20 files.
For now, I only manage to get all 20 files read into my program(I stored all file data into one single -- (String docBus), but I have need help with extracting words(word by word) from (String docBus) into a String Array... btw, the files contains punctuation,numbers...etc...but all I need is to count words frequency...so I need to avoid those punctuation,numbers in my program...
here is my code so far:

```
public class Count extends javax.swing.JFrame {

ArrayList<String> fileBusName = new ArrayList<String>();
String docBus = "";

private void returnBusFilenName(){
    String str = "";
    for(int i = 1; i <= 20; i++){
        str = "nlg/bus" + i + ".txt";
        fileBusName.add(str);
    }
}

private String getFile(String file){
    String strLine = "", str = "";
    try{

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while((strLine = in.readLine()) != null){
            str += strLine + "\n ";
        }
        in.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    return str;
}

private void getDocBus(){
    returnBusFilenName();
    for(int i=0; i<=19; i++){
        docBus = docBus + getFile(fileBusName.get(i));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using `java.util.Scanner`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(inputFile);
scanner.useDelimiter("[^a-zA-Z]"); // non alphabets act as delimeters
String word = scanner.next();
```

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously recommend handling the files as a stream and updating your word count as you go, instead of reading all the files into memory and then reading over that string.

Probably the easiest way to do this is to have a Map that holds each word you find and it's found. Your update function can be something like:

```
String s = //method that scans until a delimiter is found
if (map.get(s)) == null) {
   map.put(s, 1);
} else {
   map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
}
```

Of course, you're abusing autoboxing by doing this, but it's easy to write up, and you can optimize for performance later.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your input file size is considerable large e.g. in GBs, TBs or more, you may be interested in doing the same job using Hadoop and MapReduce process. For lesser data input, however, they would be not suitable. However, in both cases you can use [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) to analyze and tokenize your input text. Lucene is basically for indexing and searching of very large data, however you can still use it for your problem because its Analyzer and Tokenizer framework is very good for situations like yours.

And if you don't want to any of the above, you have to just replace all punctuations and numbers with some other character which will not interfere with next process e.g. space ' '. You can achieve this using regular expressions. Next, you can find the frequency of words using regular expression again if you are concerned with some predefined words. If you need to calculate frequency of all words present in the input, you can still use regular expressions to get it done. First match a word pattern using RegEx next for each of the matched word you can iterate through, just maintain a hash map with each word as key and just increment hash map's values based on keys. This method also has advanced filtering options like not counting frequencies for words having length less than 2 or alikes. While writing this answer I got a good [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Regular-Expressions/CalculatingWordFrequencieswithRegularExpressions.htm) doing the exact same. :)
Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple of recommendations on this one:

1. `StringBuilder` should be used instead of `String` across the board.  The more files you handle, the more using `String` will get you
2. (Word) tokenization is a non-trivial task.  There are many fine libraries out there to help you get a collection of words.  From here, you can make this a unique collection or not unique collection.  Since you need count, each occurrence is unique.  So on to a recommendation for a tokenizer, I would suggest a Penn Treebank Tokenizer, such as [here at CMU](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&ved=0CG8QFjAH&url=http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/project/listen/NLP/Parsers/Stanford/stanford-parser-2005-07-21/src/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBTokenizer.java&ei=O1kIUOepL5Sk8gSAnMmXBA&usg=AFQjCNHHKz8InDQSPO3E43of03ngDyfG1g)